# How to assign more than one user via AWS CLI to a group?

Tags: aws-cli

Trying to assign multiple users to groups using json. Created a json file, and runnign the following:
`aws iam add-user-to-group --cli-input-json file://c:\awscli\json\iam-add-user-to-group.json`

Json content is:

`{
    "GroupName": "devops",
    "UserName": ["devop1", "devop2"]
}`

and getting an error:
`Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter UserName, value: ['devop1', 'devop2'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

With the community help, changed incorrect json, and realized - there is no way to run any bulk add/remove scripts in AWS CLI.

Comment: If it says "Invalid JSON", then it's probably invalid JSON. Yours, Captain Obvious.

Comment: This is a low quality question and should probably be closed.

Comment: I'm just trying to get over 200 users to be assigned to groups via script, and running it one user at a time does not make sense. So the question is not about the error but about doable or not, and it looks lie it is not.

Answer (score 0):

That's **not a valid JSON**. This is:

```
{
    "GroupName": "devops",
    "UserName": [
        "devop1",
        "devop2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: It looks like add-user-to-group will not take more than one user. Getting the following with correct jason- `Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter UserName, value: ['devop1', 'devop2'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`. Tnx!